# how do i change the colour of my model back to the default modelling colour

Tags: modeling, sculpting

im fairly new to blender and ive been working on a model for a few days now and all of a sudden the head of my model has turned black, and i cant seem to find anything to change it back. the only thing i can say is i was messing around with a few of the tools on the left (the colour map and a few below that one) and the face turned black after selecting one of those tools, and wont change back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the "color" attribute of the mesh. Or simply using the paint tool within the sculpting tab tools and paint the mesh white.

Comment: painting over in white fixed it. thank you for helping!